# Using Spring Boot 2 OAuth Client and Resourceserver in the same context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'd like my spring boot application to serve a protected frontend, as well as being an API resource server for said frontend at the same time, but I can't get the oauth stuff working.

What I want is the spring boot application to return a 302 redirect to the oauth server (gitlab in my case) when the browser requests the index.html without a token, so the user is sent to the login form. But I also want that the API to return a 401 when the API is called without a token, as I think a 302 redirect to a login page is not very useful there.

In pseudo code:

```
if document_url == /index.html and token not valid
  return 302 https//gitlab/loginpage
if document_url == /api/restcall and token not valid
  return 401
server document_url
```

I am working with spring boot 2.1, regarding oauth my pom.xml contains

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is my naive try in the SecurityConfig

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html").authenticated()
        .and()
            .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/gitlab")

        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/restcall").authenticated()
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Both configurations (oauth2Login and oauth2ResourceServer) work fine for themself. But as soon as I combine them the last one wins (so in the above example there would be no 302 and the browser would also see a 401 for the index.html). I presume they share some configuration objects so the last write wins.

Is there an (easy) way to get what I want? I know spring can do almost anything, but I would very much not to end up manually configuring a gazillion beans ...

**Update:**

I've made a minimal example (including @dur's suggestion) of my code [here](https://github.com/jeromewaibel/doubleoauth)

Comment: Did you try multiple configurations?

Comment: You mean split my definition into two classes SecurityConfig1 and SecurityConfig2? Yes, that didn't work either. Depending on the load order one of them still was winning.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It should work. You have to restrict your configs each for another URL pattern.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create multiple configurations and restrict them only to specific URL patterns using `requestMatcher`. Based on your example, your configurations should look like this:

**SecurityConfigHTML**

```
public class SecurityConfigHTML extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/index.html")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login().loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/gitlab");
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfigAPI**

```
public class SecurityConfigAPI extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/call")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I'd like to add that this is documented here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity

Answer (score 0):

**SecurityConfigHTML**

I think we should include `/oauth2/**` into the request matchers, otherwise the `oauth2Login` will not work.
[404 http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIvbJ.png)

```
public class SecurityConfigHTML extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/index.html", "/oauth2/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```