# Should we expose REST API as an OAuth 2 resource server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot application exposing several REST API endpoints. I want to enable google oauth authentication (authorization code grant) on it. I am guessing what is correct way to do this out of following  options:

1. Have separate application as OAuth 2 client (i.e. with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` dependency and make the existing app a resource server (i.e. with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` dependency)

   a. [This Udemy's course](https://www.udemy.com/course/oauth2-in-spring-boot-applications/) keeps two application separate: [resource server](https://github.com/simplyi/ResourceServer), [OAuth 2 client](https://github.com/simplyi/SocialLoginWebClient). Then it seem to need a [proxy REST endpoint](https://github.com/simplyi/PhotoAppWebClient/blob/d98d8eee03533f473c1a3ebad1b0c50460a77cfa/src/main/java/com/appsdeveloperblog/ws/clients/photoappwebclient/controllers/AlbumsController.java#L42) in oauth
   2 client project corresponding to every REST endpoint in resource server. REST end point in OAuth 2 client [retrieves access token](https://github.com/simplyi/PhotoAppWebClient/blob/d98d8eee03533f473c1a3ebad1b0c50460a77cfa/src/main/java/com/appsdeveloperblog/ws/clients/photoappwebclient/PhotoAppWebClientApplication.java#L25) and adds it to every request to corresponding REST endpoint in resource server.

   b. [This stackoverflow threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805033/using-spring-boot-2-oauth-client-and-resourceserver-in-the-same-context) talks about making same application both OAuth2 client as well as resource server
2. Make the existing app OAuth 2 client. (that is include `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` dependency) and simply require user to be authenticated to access REST endpoint URLs.

I have following doubts:

**Q1.** Should REST API always be exposed as resource server? And if yes, then is approach 2 not-so-recommended way? (as it does not expose existing REST API as resource server but as a part of OAuth client with restricted access to those APIs)?

**Q2.** If approach 2 is not fine, then which of approaches (1.a) and (1.b) are preferred or when to prefer one above other? (I believe (1.a) is more suitable when we want single OAuth client as a point of access for several different resource servers.)

Answer (score 0):

In OAuth2 world, a REST API is a **resource-server** by definition.

In your scenario, Google currently is an **authorization-server**. You could hide it behind a Keycloak instance or something else capable of user identity federation if you need to extend to other identity providers (Github, Facebook, etc.) or want some roles definition, but as Google serve JWT access-tokens, you can use it for you resource-server security (if google IDs are enough for your security rules).

In both cases (Google directly or with an OIDC authorization-server in the middle), you can find sample configuration [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) (or [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) if you prefer to stick to `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` but it requires more Java conf as you can see in tutorials).

I personnaly don't like to merge client(s), resource-server(s) and authorization-server(s). My clients are generally mobile and web with client-side rendering (Angular), but even for spring clients I'd keep it separate.

There is a special case, thought: when a **resource-server** delegates some of its processing to another, then, by definition, it is a **client too**. In that case, it is possible that security requirements and mechanisms are pretty different:

- is your API authenticating in its own name (using client credentials flow)? In that case, you might use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` to negotiate access-token to be used when issuing requests to other service.
- is your API issuing requests in the name of authenticated user and does the other service know about the authorization-server which issued user authentication? In that case, you can forward the token you received
- is the service you are consuming not OAuth2 at all? (just requires basic auth header for instance)